# Qt and Windows Executable Version Information

Tags: c++, qt, versioning

My Windows Qt widgets application uses a "version.h" file and an "RC" file to populate the version information strings against an executable.

The version.h looks like this...

```
#ifndef VERSION_H
#define VERSION_H

#define VERSION_MAJOR                           1
#define VERSION_MINOR                           0
#define VERSION_BUILD                           3

#define VER_FILEVERSION           VERSION_MAJOR,VERSION_MINOR,VERSION_BUILD,0
#define STR_FILEVERSION                     VERSION_MAJOR##"."##VERSION_MINOR##"."VERSION_BUILD##".0"

// Keep the product version as fixed
#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION        1.0.0.0
#define STR_PRODUCTVERSION          "1.0.0.0\0"

#define STR_COMPANYNAME                     "MyCompany"
#define STR_FILEDESCRIPTION             "MyFile"
#define STR_INTERNALNAME                    "MyFile"
#define STR_LEGALCOPYRIGHT              "Copyright © 2017 MyCompany"
#define STR_LEGALTRADEMARKS1            "All Rights Reserved"
#define STR_LEGALTRADEMARKS2            STR_LEGALTRADEMARKS1
#define STR_ORIGINALFILENAME            "MyApp.exe"
#define STR_PRODUCTNAME                     "MyApp"

#define STR_COMPANYDOMAIN                   "mywebsite.com"

#endif // VERSION_H
```

And the RC file looking like:

```
IDI_APP_ICON    ICON    DISCARDABLE     "MyApp.ico"

#include <windows.h>
#include "version.h"

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     VER_FILEVERSION
PRODUCTVERSION  VER_PRODUCTVERSION
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904E4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName",        STR_COMPANYNAME
            VALUE "FileDescription",    STR_FILEDESCRIPTION
            VALUE "FileVersion",        STR_FILEVERSION
            VALUE "InternalName",       STR_INTERNALNAME
            VALUE "LegalCopyright",     STR_LEGALCOPYRIGHT
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks1",   STR_LEGALTRADEMARKS1
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks2",   STR_LEGALTRADEMARKS2
            VALUE "OriginalFilename",   STR_ORIGINALFILENAME
            VALUE "ProductName",        STR_PRODUCTNAME
            VALUE "ProductVersion",     STR_PRODUCTVERSION
        END
    END

    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252
    END
END
```

And for completeness, the ".pro" file has this line inside:

```
RC_FILE    = MyApp.rc
```

This all seems to work OK: when I right-click the exe and go to the details tab, I can see the version information and all other strings from the combined version.h and RC files.

However, if I increase the any one of the VERSION_XXX #define values and build the application, I've noticed that the reported "File version" hasn't changed - only when I do a "rebuild" does the version change.

I don't really want to have to do a complete rebuild every time I increase the version information (mainly VERSION_BUILD at the moment) so what may I need to do in order to get this information updated each time the exe is built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `qmake` doesn't support dependencies of `RC_FILE`. So what can be done about that?

1) The simplest and quickest approach is to make use of `touch`: if `MyApp.rc` (almost) never changes, we can force its timestamp to follow one of `version.h`. Then something like:

> MyApp.pro

```
TARGET = MyApp
win*:RC_FILE = $${TARGET}.rc
win*:!build_pass:touch($$RC_FILE, version.h)
# ... more to follow
```

accompanied with `qmake && make` will do the trick.

2) Another seemingly easy solution is **not** to use `RC_FILE` at all, but let `qmake` automatically generate resource script from the predefined variables: `VERSION`, `QMAKE_TARGET_COMPANY`, `QMAKE_TARGET_DESCRIPTION`, etc. See [qmake Platform Notes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-platform-notes.html) for a full list.

It's enough just to add `VERSION = x.y.z.n` (and also remove `RC_FILE = MyApp.rc`) to your `.pro` file to enable this feature.

This is sufficient for most Qt applications, as long as they use own Qt resource system, while Windows .rc script is needed for application ICON(s) and VERSIONINFO only.

An example of the above:

> version.pri

```
RC_ICONS = MyApp.ico
VERSION = 1.0.3.0
QMAKE_TARGET_COMPANY = MyCompany
QMAKE_TARGET_DESCRIPTION = MyFile
QMAKE_TARGET_COPYRIGHT = "Copyright © 2017 MyCompany"
QMAKE_TARGET_PRODUCT = MyApp
RC_CODEPAGE = 1252
RC_LANG = 0x0409
```

> MyApp.pro

```
TARGET = MyApp
#win*:RC_FILE = $${TARGET}.rc
win*:include(version.pri)
# ... more to follow
```

Unfortunately, this poses another problem: if you still need `version.h` in your C++ source tree, you have to synchronize it somehow with your `version.pri`. I think that using `QMAKE_SUBSTITUTES` to auto-generate `version.h` is the best choice. However, adding a bunch of `DEFINES+=...` is also an idea.

3) You can create a custom target in your `.pro` file and take care of compiling the resource script yourself. For example:

> MyApp.pro

```
TARGET = MyApp
#win*:RC_FILE = $${TARGET}.rc
win* {
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += windows_resource
    windows_resource.target = $${TARGET}_res$${first(QMAKE_EXT_OBJ)}
    windows_resource.depends = $${TARGET}.rc version.h
    msvc:windows_resource.commands = $$QMAKE_RC /fo $$windows_resource.target $${TARGET}.rc
    else:windows_resource.commands = $$QMAKE_RC $${TARGET}.rc $$windows_resource.target
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$windows_resource.target
    LIBS += $$windows_resource.target
}
# ... more to follow
```